# Error in SVAR function of vars package

Tags: r, time-series, economics, autoregressive-models

Using the vars package, I am trying to replicate a standard 4-variable SVAR model with quarterly data and 61 observations. Matrix A has a recursive structure and no restrictions were placed on matrix B (just identified model). The original model was estimated in Stata with the same dataset.

I get the same (correct) results in the reduced-form VAR estimation, but once I get to the SVAR part, I get this message repeatedly:

```
Error in solve.default(infgamma): 
system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 1.90759e-16
```

Probably I am doing something wrong but I do not know what it is. I would appreciate any help.

Here is my code:

```
Model1 <- VAR(data, p=4, type="const") 
    summary(Model1)

AMATRIX = matrix(c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 
               NA, NA, 0, 0,
               NA, NA, NA, 0,
               NA, NA, NA, NA), nrow=4,ncol=4, byrow = T)

Model2 <- SVAR(x=Model1, Amat = AMATRIX)

summary(Model2)
```

PS: The SVAR function uses the default scoring algorithm by Amisano & Giannini (1997), which is the estimation method I would like to use.